# matlab , working with 2 instances at once

Tags: matlab

this bug is really annoying me

so i have a few scripts (costfunction.m and others .. , doing neural networks)

i want to work on 2 projects at once , so i create a folder for the second project, i copy all the scripts from the first project into the second, i open costfunction.m in both folders(this means I open them in matlab so i have 2 matlabs running at once) , and when I edit something like this

input_layer_size = 400; % 20x20 Input Images of Digits

hidden_layer_size = 25;

on my first project , I used 400 now i want to use 25 for my second project so i put 25

input_layer_size = 25; % 20x20 Input Images of Digits

hidden_layer_size = 25;

and I hit enter , and to my surprise BOTH of the costfunction.m scripts get edited out , so when i open the one on my first project I find input_layer_size = 25; instead of 400

Remember i only edited the second one and not the first one

I can't find any solution to this , how can the developers miss something like this?

Answer (score 0):

solved it , you have to open the costfunction.m tab and reopen it , because matlab automatically opens the project 1's script not the second